# Выводим максимальное число в PostgeSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть такой вот запрос:

```
select max (number::integer) from table where id = ?
```

Это поле текстовое (как изначально решили сделать для удобства, так и поехало). Но вот незадача - если кто туда воткнет знак '-' или '/', '\' и прочее, то конечно выйдет эксепшн на `::integer`.

Как можно реализовать запрос, чтобы выводило именно максимальное число из полей, в которых нет этих знаков?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `PostgreSQL` есть регулярги. Попробуйте так:

```
select max (number::integer) from table where id = ? and number !~ '[^0-9]'
```

Скорость выборки конечно просядет, но зато не получите исключение при конвертировании в `INT`